# Automate navigation with c# on Monodevelop

Tags: c#, webview, gtk, monodevelop

I need to automate a navigation on a website (Login, than click on specific button, than get the source code to analyze it)

I need to do this with c# on monodevelop So that will be compatible with linux sytems.

I created a window and add to it an webview and oppened my site we replace my site by stackoverflow for example.

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using GtkSharp;
using WebKit;

namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main () {
            Application.Init ();
            Window winnn = new MainWindow ();
            winnn.Destroyed += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
                Application.Quit ();
            };
            WebView webView = new WebView ();
            webView.Open ("http://stackoverflow.com");
            winnn.Add (webView);
            winnn.ShowAll ();
            Application.Run ();
        }

        public static void charged(WebView webView){
            Console.WriteLine ("here we are charged");
        }

        /*public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }*/
    }
}
```

The problem is that i dont know how to manipulate the page, get the webviw and get elements from it ans put the login and password and get event of page loaded for exemple to do another think.

And here is the code of my mainWindow:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("yes 3");
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    public static void charged(MainWindow MainWindow){
        Console.WriteLine ("here we are charged");
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up ATK; that's the accessibility/automation toolkit GTK+ uses, and WebKitGTK uses it too. Does Gtk# provide an ATK binding?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that i don't know how to manipulate elements from the webView